# Serialize XML document to String

Tags: android, xml-serialization

Is it possible to serialize instance of Document class to String in Android??
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Simple is a high performance XML serialization and configuration framework for Java

Works for android too. http://simple.sourceforge.net/

For serializing objects and etc. JSON is great. An implementation for android: Gson on http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/